# Столкнулся с проблемой при работе обновлении записей в БД postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql

у меня есть два таблицы(`products`, `baskets`) в этом примере у меня есть массив `id` товаров, которые находятся в корзине, например `[1,1,1,2,3]`, т.е. тут есть 3 одинаковых товара
но при удалении этой корзины, нужно увеличить количество товаров на 1, если у нас в этом примере 3 одинаковых товара, то в таблице `products` товар с `id===1` нужно увеличить его свойство `count` на 1 если товар в корзине встречается только один раз, но у нас их 3 и след нужно увеличить значение `count` на 3.
так вот, при написании вот этого кода, у меня увеличивает значение не на 3 как нужно, а только на 1

```
await Promise.all(
    products_array.map(async id => {
        let product = await ProductModel.findOne({ where: {id}}) 
        // находим продукт по id
        let updatedProduct = await ProductModel.update({count: product.count+1}, {where: {id}})
        // обновляем count продукта на 1
        return updatedProduct
    })
)
```

но при таком написании, все работает как и задумано

```
await Promise.all(
    products_array.map(async id => {
        return ProductModel.increment('count', { where: { id }}); 
    })
)
```

так вот, как обновить свойство продукта первым способом и почему оно не работает, можете разъяснить в чем моя ошибка.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы параллельно пытаетесь обновить одну и ту же запись БД и результат выполнения что первого, что второго "написания" зависит от случайных факторов. Ваш код, это - пример [состояния гонки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8).

Лучшим решением будет заранее посчитать размер увеличения счётчика и выполнить (параллельно) редактирование записей с уникальными идентификаторами.

```js
const products_array = [1,1,1,2,3];

const reducedProductsArray = products_array.reduce(
  (acc, x) => {
    acc[x] = (acc[x] || 0) + 1;
    return acc;
  },
  {},
);

await Promise.all(
  Object.entries(reducedProductsArray).map(
    ([id, val]) => ProductModel.increment({ count: val }, { where: { id }})
  )
);
```

Пример вызова метода `increment` я взял [тут](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7268#issuecomment-514643840), сам не пользуюсь sequelize, так что не могу проверить корректность.